# How to add manifest <requestedPrivileges> info into delphi project

Tags: delphi, uac, manifest, delphi-xe

What is the easiest way to add the `<requestedPrivileges>` manifest info to a Delphi XE project (.exe)?

Is it possible to add just the required node like:

```
<requestedPrivileges>   
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/> 
</requestedPrivileges>
```

or do i have to add the whole manifest file, like?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" name="VistaLogonCustomizer.exe" type="*"/>
  <description>elevate execution level</description>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
   <security>
     <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/>
     </requestedPrivileges>
   </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
   <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" processorArchitecture="*"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

If I have to add the whole manifest file, do I have then a conflict with the build in manfest file (which is generated when the project-option "Activate Runtime-Theme" is set to true)?

Comment: You have to add the whole manifest and you have to disable "Activate Runtime-Theme". You can either compile it using the resource compiler or include a separate .manifest file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to add just the required node

Absolutely NO. Manifest is an XML document and XML documents must be well-formed. 
Here is XML schema description:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191(VS.85).aspx

Note the required elements and attributes.

Answer (score 17):

Here are some links

[Delphi and Windows Vista User Account Control](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33942)

[Vista UAC Manifest](http://ruminatedrumblings.blogspot.com/2008/03/vista-uac-manifest.html)

> Here are the steps:

```
Create XML file with following content: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.1.1.1"
   processorArchitecture="X86"
   name="YourApplicationExeName"
   type="win32"/>
  <description>elevate execution level</description>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
  <security>
   <requestedPrivileges>
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
   </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
  </trustInfo>
 </assembly>
```

> Name this XML file as YourApplicationName.manifest
>
> Create a text file with following
>   content:

```
1 24 "YourApplicationName.manifest"
```

> Name this text file as YourApplicationName.RC using the
>   command line execute following command:
>
> brcc32 YourApplicationName.RC -foYourApplicationName.REC
>
> This will create a new resource file called YourApplicationName.REC Copy
>   this YourApplicationName.REC file in to the resource path of your
>   application. Include this resource file into the DPR of you application,
>
> as like:
>
> {$R YourApplicationName.REC} Finally build your application - it is now ready to get admin rights

Comment: I'm feeling dense today. Could you please explain how those links answer the question? Summarize their contents here, or point out which parts of those articles are most important for the immediate task.

Comment: There is no need (nor should any development environment require you) to drop to a command prompt or run a separate command. Just add your resource script to the project (**Project** -> **Add to project** -> `wumpa.rc` -> **Open**). Delphi will now compile the resource script. Also note, the resource script file can be called whatever you want. We always call it `wumpa.rc`, as in *Hunt the wumpa* - a reference to the amount of work to discover that Delphi (unlike Visual Studio) can compile resource scripts.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the manifest file must be called <appliationname>.manifest or would <SomeGenericName>.manifest also work?

Answer (score 13):

You should add the entire manifest. You'll need to disable the IDE generated version in the project.

The advantage of this is that you will have full and transparent control of your manifest. For example you may want to add a DPI aware entry so that your app looks good at higher font scaling values.